# *modify* UIbutton position (Iphone SDK)

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I'm playing around with UIbuttons, just to get a feel on what can really be done with them. I have only one problem so far:

How do I *modify* the position of a UIButton?

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *senderB = sender;

   CGPoint position = senderB.frame.origin;
   CGSize size = senderB.frame.size;
   senderB.frame = CGRectMake(position.x,position.y + 10,size.width,size.height);
}
```

The above works just fine, however, creating a new CGrect for every time I want to simply *change* one seems rather inefficient to me.

Is there any way for me to directly set the values of senderB.frame.origin.x, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Notice that 'someview.frame' returns a CGRect by value, not by reference or pointer or whatever. That's why you get the 'Lvalue required' error.

However, setting the frame like you're doing is plenty fast.

Answer (score 13):

I usually do it like this:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
buttonFrame.origin.y += 10;
button.frame = buttonFrame;
```

Comment: Interesting way of doing it! Should help :)

Answer (score 4):

The frame property is read only. What you can do is copying the current frame with

```
CGRect btFrame = senderB.frame; 
btFrame.origin.x += 10;
senderB.frame = btFrame;
```